# Davening: which parts are recited silently?

Tags: tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, loud-quiet

Which parts in Shacharis should be said aloud, and which parts should be recited silently to yourself? Obviously the Amidah should be silent, but what about Hodu, Boruch Sheamar, etc.?

Comment: The halacha [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 101:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.101?lang=en ) states that one davening (the Amidah) must ideally recite the words loud enough for him to hear what he is saying but not so loud as to disturb others. If that is not possible, the words must be formed by the mouth even if they are not audible. 

This law applies to the Amidah; the volume of other parts of davenning is not specified except for certain sections that have to be recited so that others can hear. But  **no part of the davenning should ideally be recited silently.**

Comment: And why'd you say that. Elaborate. Sources too.

Comment: It depends on your custom. In my experience, Ashkenazi shuls say *psukei d'zimra* silently, with the chazzan just saying the last verse of each paragraphs out loud, while Sefardic communities have the chazzan say the whole thing out loud, with the rest of the congregation sometimes joining along (more often on Shabbat than during the week).

Answer (score 1):

Three items that I know are said aloud (I think they are mentioned in Talmud Brachot. I'll edit in location when I find it):

- יהא שמה רבא.. of the Kaddish
- ברכו את ה המבורך ... in response to the Chazan or Torah Oleh's ברכו
- אמן response to each blessing of the chazan's *amidah* repetition